# Load matomo tracking with a javascript function

Tags: javascript, matomo

Load the matomo tracking code with a javascript function don't set cookies.

The matomo tracking should be loaded, when a function is called. The source script loaded in the `<head>` works. The `_paq` array is filled. The function is called. But cookies don't saved.
PS: with Google Analytics it works.

```
var functions_object = {};

functions_object["matomo"] = function () {
    var _paq = _paq || [];
    /* tracker methods like "setCustomDimension" should be called before "trackPageView" */
    _paq.push(['trackPageView']);
    _paq.push(['enableLinkTracking']);
    (function() {
    var u="//www.example.com/matomo/";
    _paq.push(['setTrackerUrl', u+'matomo.php']);
    _paq.push(['setSiteId', '99']);
    var d=document, g=d.createElement('script'), s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    g.type='text/javascript'; g.async=true; g.defer=true; g.src=u+'matomo.js'; s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s);
    })();
};
```

The complete script is embedded in the `<head>` (>1000 rows).

I call the functions in the `functions_object` inside another function with a for loop. This works fine by all, except matomo.

comment out the lines `(function() {` and `})();` have no effect.

The matomo code works outside the function, also blank in the script, cookies are saved.

Answer (score -1):

could you please report this bug with a list of steps to reproduce in the Matomo issue tracker directly? This may be an issue in Matomo if you can reproduce it. Thanks! http://www.github.com/matomo-org/matomo/issues/